# Setting OS variable in Azure DevOps pipeline doesn't work

Tags: linux, yaml, azure-devops-pipelines

In YAML pipeline I'm attempting to set OS variable on Linux Agent so Cypress can look it up:

```
  - script: export CYPRESS_key=ala
    displayName: "Set key"

  - script: echo $(CYPRESS_key)
    displayName: "Print key"
```

unfortunately the OS variable is never set.
The output is:

```
/home/vsts/work/_temp/321aacd-cadd-4a16-a4d1-db7927deacde.sh: line 1: CYPRESS_key: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(command)` and `${variable}` you are using wrong brackets

```
- script: export CYPRESS_key=ala
  displayName: "Set key"

- script: echo ${CYPRESS_key}
  displayName: "Print key"

- script: echo $(cat /etc/os-release)
  displayName: "Print file content"
```

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables in Linux are accessed as `$ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_NAME`, not `$(ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_NAME)`.

Comment: Did both the 1st version displays nothing at all.